# recursive multiple match in multidimensional php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to match all "keywords" in a multidimesional array:

```
$array = array(
    'green' => 'keyword',
    'orange',
    'keyword',
    'black' => array(
        'purple' => 'text',
        'brown',
        'pink' => 'keyword'
    ),
    'white' => array(
        'red',
        'yellow' => 'keyword',
        'blue'
    ),
    'violet',
    'gray'
);
```

Then I would like to access the match results like:

```
$matches[0][0]
$matches[2]
$matches[3][2]
....
```

What should I use? I tried with array_filter but doesn't work.. also it might have to be recursive

```
function findInArray($array){
    $array = array_filter($array, function($array){
        return ($array == 'keyword');
    });
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: you should add the code wherein you are using it too, add the usage with the input array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can did the thing by using `array_filter`.

Online check [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aCQFt)

```
$arr = array();

$str = 'keyword';
$arr[] = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($str) {
            global $arr;
            if(is_array($var)){             
                $arr[] = array_filter($var, function($var2) use ($str) {
                    return preg_match("/$str/i", $var2);
                });
            }else{
                return preg_match("/$str/i", $var);
            }           
        });

function getL2Keys($array){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $sub) {
        $result = array_merge($result, $sub);
    }        
    return $result;
}

$arr = getL2Keys($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [pink] => keyword
    [yellow] => keyword
    [green] => keyword
    [0] => keyword
)
```

Comment: can you add the $array example? It is not working with my array

Comment: so please post your array.

Comment: @neoDev, I am working on it. try the current script.

Comment: @neoDev, Done the script.